# Make UIBarButtonItem transparent iOS 7/8

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

i know there are a lot of question/answers about this topic, but can't find a fitting answer. 
I building a UIBar programmatically. My own buttons (png with transparancy) are having a back fill instead of showing the background trough.

The system UIBarButton's are working perfect, but not my own.

works:

```
UIBarButtonItem *exportButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                       target:self                                                                                                    
                       action:@selector(tapExportButton:)];
```

not works:

```
UIBarButtonItem *favButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                initWithImage:[UIImage 
                   imageNamed:@"FavoriteStar"] 
                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                       target:self 
                       action:@selector(toggleFavorite:)];
```

the inner part of the png is transparent in my gfx editor

[image: the inner of the star (png) is transparent]

the inner part is black when i use it as a UIBarButtonItem, but not the background picture...

[image: the inner part is shown black]

What can i do to make it transparent?

Regards,

Jeroen Wolff

Answer (score 0):

I am revising your code for better understanding

```
UIBarButtonItem *favButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
            initWithImage:[UIImage 
               imageNamed:@"FavoriteStar"] 
                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                   target:self 
                   action:@selector(toggleFavorite:)];
```

below are some points that needs to be taken care of:
 1. Your navigation bar should be transparent.
 2. Use a PNG file (for better quality) with its transparent background.
 3. You can also use the below code for reference

```
    UIButton *btnBack=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.frame=CGRectMake(0, 29.5, 38, 25);
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_backSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnbackClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *barbutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnBack];
[barbutton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barbutton;
```

I have used a custom button as bar button.

I am really want to hear from you. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Abdul, but now the image stays black. Before it turned white (i don't know why it became white, i was dawn in black). So i will change the draw color in the png's

Comment: Or is there another way to change the color of the image of the button.

Comment: When i make a image with the RenderingMode like this, it works [[UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteStarNormal"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]